# AngularJS Factory $http Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to use a factory for my REST Controller which returns an array of Strings. I want to reuse the function in my services.js.

**This is my HTML (Autocomplete input field)**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="vertrag.vertrag.v00Lobcode.lobCode" typeahead-wait-ms="1000"
typeahead="lobcode for lobcode in getLobcode($viewValue)" typeahead-loading="loadingLobcodes">
```

**Controller**

```
 $scope.getLobcode = function(val) {
    Autocomplete.get(val).then(function(promise) {
        console.log(promise);
    });
};
```

**services.js**

```
AppServices.factory('Autocomplete', function($http, API_URL) {
return {
    get: function(val) {
        var promise = $http.get(API_URL+'/leistobjekts/autocomplete/'+val.toUpperCase())
            .then(function(response) {
                return response.data;
        });
        return promise;
    }
};
```

});

**My Exception**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at http://localhost:8080/bootstrap/js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js:3553:24
at deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (http://localhost:8080/js/lib/angular/angular.js:11498:81)
at deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (http://localhost:8080/js/lib/angular/angular.js:11498:81)
at http://localhost:8080/js/lib/angular/angular.js:11584:26
at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (http://localhost:8080/js/lib/angular/angular.js:12608:28)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (http://localhost:8080/js/lib/angular/angular.js:12420:31)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (http://localhost:8080/js/lib/angular/angular.js:12712:24)
at http://localhost:8080/js/lib/angular/angular.js:14220:36
at completeOutstandingRequest (http://localhost:8080/js/lib/angular/angular.js:4349:10)
at http://localhost:8080/js/lib/angular/angular.js:4650:7
```

Actually I get back the right results I need (console) but the error says that anything is not working properly. And the autocomplete is not showing anything.

This is my autocomplete function which already worked for me. But its not really reusable.

```
$scope.getLobcode = function(val) {
    return $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: API_URL+'/leistobjekts/autocomplete/'+val.toUpperCase(),
        cache:true

    }).then(function(res){
        console.log(res.data);
        var lobcodes = [];
        angular.forEach(res.data, function(item){
            lobcodes.push(item);
        });
          return lobcodes;
        });
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return your promise like this:

```
$scope.getLobcode = function(val) {
    return Autocomplete.get(val);
};
```

or simply do this:

```
$scope.getLobcode = Autocomplete.get;
```